# iteration in parallel processing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, iteration, python-itertools

I think I am close but I cannot figure out the right way to iterate the inputs. This is an example of my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial
from itertools import product

def f(n, x, y):
    return print("{} {} {}".format(n, x, y))

n = 3

c = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
d = [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(3)
    func = partial(f, n)
    p.starmap(func, product(zip(c,d), repeat=2))
```

This is the result:

```
3 ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]) ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9])
3 ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]) ([4, 5, 6], [10, 11, 12])
3 ([4, 5, 6], [10, 11, 12]) ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9])
3 ([4, 5, 6], [10, 11, 12]) ([4, 5, 6], [10, 11, 12])
```

but what I want is

```
3 ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]) 
3 ([1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12])
3 ([4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])
3 ([4, 5, 6], [10, 11, 12])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expected output is simply the product of `c` and `d`, so there's no reason to `zip` or to repeat.

Change:

```
p.starmap(func, product(zip(c,d), repeat=2))
```

to:

```
p.starmap(func, product(c, d))
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/GoodWorthwhileLeadership